# Select number of value occurences for multiple fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL. I have a table that looks like this:

```
   rawID | a1a | a1b | a2a | a2b | a2c | ...
     1   |  2  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  2  | ...
     2   |  2  |  2  |  0  |  0  |  0  | ...
     3   |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  2  | ...
     4   |  2  |  1  |  2  |  1  |  2  | ...
```

*The possible values for the fields are predefined in a separate "response" table and range from 0-2.

I want a result that gives me the occurence of each value for each field. I've seen similar questions as this, but only ever deal with one field.

I would like my result to look like this:

```
   response | a1a | a1b | a2a | a2b | a2c | ...
      0     |  1  |  1  |  2  |  2  |  1  | ...
      1     |  0  |  2  |  1  |  2  |  0  | ...
      2     |  3  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  3  | ...
```

This table has the number of times each value ("response") occurred for each field.

Thanks guys,

Comment: Do you have an explicit list or that possible responses (0,1,2) somewhere defined? Otherwise, we'd need a `SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2` to start it, or worse yet: if it is subject to change, and we should list dynamic values, we have to start out with `SELECT DISTINCT a1a FROM table UNION SELECT DISTINCT a1b......` etc.

Comment: That is not a programming question. It doesn't seem like you showed the smallest effort to resolve the problem yourself. Please hire a consultant or programmer if you need such things to be resolved. This is not the salvation army.

Comment: @Wrikken - Yes the possible responses are defined in a seperate table

Comment: @mwhs - I can appreciate this problem might have an obvious/easy solution for you. I'm not a MySQL expert and I actually did spend a considerable about of time trying to figure it out myself and from previous SO posts. This problem was solved below and now others can benefit from it too hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT
  response,
  sum(a1a = response) a1aCount,
  sum(a1b = response) a1bCount,
  sum(a2a = response) a2aCount,
  sum(a2b = response) a2bCount,
  sum(a2c = response) a2cCount
FROM t, r
GROUP BY response
```

Output:

```
| RESPONSE | A1ACOUNT | A1BCOUNT | A2ACOUNT | A2BCOUNT | A2CCOUNT |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|        0 |        1 |        1 |        2 |        2 |        1 |
|        1 |        0 |        2 |        1 |        2 |        0 |
|        2 |        3 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5a91e/1).

This will work regardless of the amount of items in the `response` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works (we suppose your table name is "responses"):

```
SELECT 0 as response, SUM(r.a1a = 0) as a1a, SUM(r.a1b = 0) as a1b,
SUM(r.a2a = 0) as a2a, SUM(r.a2b = 0) as a2b FROM responses r
UNION
SELECT 1 as response, SUM(r.a1a = 1) as a1a, SUM(r.a1b = 1) as a1b, 
SUM(r.a2a = 1) as a2a, SUM(r.a2b = 1) as a2b FROM responses r
UNION
SELECT 2 as response, SUM(r.a1a = 2) as a1a, SUM(r.a1b = 2) as a1b,    
SUM(r.a2a = 2) as a2a, SUM(r.a2b = 2) as a2b FROM responses r
```